# Change value of input with percent of page scroll in jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm using jQuery to calculate the amount of the page that is currently scrolled, and write that value to an input every time the page is scrolled.

```
var scrollAmount = $(window).scrollTop();
var documentHeight = $(document).height();
var scrollPercent = (scrollAmount / documentHeight) * 100;

$(window).scroll(function (event) {
 $(".box").val(scrollPercent);
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x3jXK/

And yet, when I try this, the input always shows zero.

I remember reading something about using `.attr()` instead of `.val()` because the displayed value won't change, but not sure how I could implement that here as it changes dynamically, not just from one to a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your vars should be inside your function, so they can be calculated on every scroll.

```
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
    var scrollAmount = $(window).scrollTop();
    var documentHeight = $(document).height();
    var scrollPercent = (scrollAmount / documentHeight) * 100;

    $(".knob").val(scrollPercent);
});
```

test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/x3jXK/1/

Comment: I can't believe this. Are they not recognized as global vars?

Comment: explanation would be nice ;-)

Comment: @MattRiva the problem is not with scoping. The problem is with the time of calculation

Comment: Ahh! That makes more sense. Thanks.

Comment: The document height _can_ change. For example when adding content or when resizing the browser window.

Comment: @JanDvorak For what I'm using it for, that's okay. But I do need it to update as the page scrolls.

Comment: @MattRiva: it will. dont worry :)

Comment: hey guys, don't forget to subtract your window height from the document height otherwise you will never show the document as 100% scrolled.